# Superscript a String in Java SE

Tags: java-8

I need to superscript a String value using java. So how can I code it?

```
System.out.println("5th");
```

There "th" should be printed as a superscript.

Comment: The console (pure text only) doesn't do any styling.

Comment: You could apply styling to some graphical output.

Answer (score 0):

As @Androbin pointed out, this is not possible in a console output.